# follow official direct2d sample but got access violation error

Tags: c++, win32gui, direct2d

Following the official tutorial of Direct2D (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-quickstart) to create a sample project with Visual Studio 2019. When running the code in x86, everything works fine while changing the platform to x64, I get an error that says: 'Exception thrown: read access violation.' in SampleD2D.cpp. (the line was commented in the code below)

the error is :

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was 0xBB18F6E8.
```

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK DemoApp::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = 0;

    if (message == WM_CREATE)
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
        DemoApp* pDemoApp = (DemoApp*)pcs->lpCreateParams;

        ::SetWindowLongPtrW(
            hwnd,
            GWLP_USERDATA,
            PtrToUlong(pDemoApp)
        );

        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        DemoApp* pDemoApp = reinterpret_cast<DemoApp*>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
            ::GetWindowLongPtrW(
                hwnd,
                GWLP_USERDATA
            )));

        bool wasHandled = false;

        if (pDemoApp)
        {
            switch (message)
            {
            case WM_SIZE:
            {
                UINT width = LOWORD(lParam);
                UINT height = HIWORD(lParam);
                pDemoApp->OnResize(width, height); // throw the error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            }
            result = 0;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;

            case WM_DISPLAYCHANGE:
            {
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
            }
            result = 0;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;

            case WM_PAINT:
            {
                pDemoApp->OnRender();
                ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL);
            }
            result = 0;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;

            case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
            result = 1;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;
            }
        }

        if (!wasHandled)
        {
            result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you change anything else? What are your system specifications?

Comment: Hey, I didn't change anything. It's windows 10 pro with i7-8700 CPU

Comment: Btw. I looked into your link and found the wrong code in Part 4 (as claimed by you). You may make a sample bug report (and say greetings from me). ;-)

Comment: MS has a bug in the sample and doesn't care to fix. Here's a better one: https://github.com/Const-me/Direct2D-demo

Comment: @Soonts I hadn't expected an exact duplicate like this. (I wonder why I didn't find it when googling...) On the other hand, OP was hardly the first one who tapped into this trap. It's a pity (for MS). ;-) (Or, is it actually valuable to sharpen your eye? Little mistakes here and there force you to (really) understand what's going on...)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm no WinAPI expert but, out of curiosity, I googled a bit. Now, I'm quite sure about OPs problem:

```
        ::SetWindowLongPtrW(
            hwnd,
            GWLP_USERDATA,
            PtrToUlong(pDemoApp)
        );
```

specifically `PtrToUlong(pDemoApp)`.

That might work for 32 bit applications but not for 64 bit.

`long` is in MS VC++ 32 bit – for x86 as well as x64 platform.

Hence, converting a pointer to `long` or `unsigned long` is good for making it wrong on x64 (as soon as the upper 32 bits are not 0 – which is probably hard to predict).

Googling into this direction I found e.g. [PtrToUlong Q/A on gamedev.net](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/480408-ptrtoulong/) with this (old) answer:

> msdn, try to avoid using these because you are casting a pointer into an unsigned long. This may work correctly on 32-bit executables but if you compile in 64-bit you may have problems.

which supports my doubts.

According to MS doc. [SetWindowLongPtrW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw), the signature is:

> ```
> LONG_PTR SetWindowLongPtrW(
>   HWND     hWnd,
>   int      nIndex,
>   LONG_PTR dwNewLong
> );
> ```

So, this should fix it:

```
        ::SetWindowLongPtrW(
            hwnd,
            GWLP_USERDATA,
            reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pDemoApp)
        );
```

Please, note the MS doc. about [`LONG_PTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types):

> **LONG_PTR**
>
> A signed long type for pointer precision. Use when casting a pointer to a long to perform pointer arithmetic.
>
> This type is declared in BaseTsd.h as follows:
>
> **C++**
>
> ```
> #if defined(_WIN64)
>  typedef __int64 LONG_PTR; 
> #else
>  typedef long LONG_PTR;
> #endif
> ```

---

Btw. I didn't understand as well

```
        DemoApp* pDemoApp = reinterpret_cast<DemoApp*>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
            ::GetWindowLongPtrW(
                hwnd,
                GWLP_USERDATA
            )));
```

According to doc. [GetWindowLongPtrW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptrw), the function returns `LONG_PTR`. So, why the `static_cast<LONG_PTR>`? A type cast should be always the last resort if absolutely necessary. (Although, I admit that WinAPI is probably unusable without.)